# Python: 0 if Null, and 1 if not

Tags: python, pandas, null

I'm trying to create a column in my data set such that any null values can be set to 0, and non-null values are set to 1. For starters, my column of data called '9Age', roughly speaking, looks like this:

```
NaN
6
5
NaN
2
NaN
3
5
4
```

Setting null values to 0 can be as easy as doing this:

```
Age0 = df['9Age'].fillna(0)
```

However, here's the rest of my attempt: Deciding whether a value is null or not was done below:

```
Age1 = df['9Age'].notnull()
```

This changes '9Age' to:

```
False
True
True
False
True
False
True
True
True
```

That is, it returns True if the observation is not null, but False if it is. Following this logic, the next step I took was writing this:

```
AgeExist = Age1.map({'False':0, 'True': 1})
```

However, to my dismay, AgeExist yields

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Or, a bunch of null values. Where did I go wrong, and what would be a better way to approach all of this?

Comment: As @John has already said `AgeExist = df['9Age'].notnull().astype(int)` will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm wildly mistaken, it's a simple matter of `True` is not `'True'`.

```
AgeExist = Age1.map({False:0, True: 1})
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Did the trick! I'm assuming this is because True and False in this case are boolean operators, and not something that was actually written in the data. 

Either way, thanks a bunch!

Comment: That's correct. Note that if my answer solves your problem, using the green check to the left `<------` to mark it as accepted is the way to go :)

Answer (score 4):

You can convert a Series of True/False values to their integer representations using `.astype`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['col'] = [np.NaN, 6, 5, np.NaN]
col = df['col'].notnull()
col.astype(int)
```